# Image height/width not saved using CKEditor and Full HTML input format

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I just upgraded a Drupal site from 5.22 to 6.22.  Everything is working except for one small problem.  I replaced FCKEditor with CKEditor using CKFinder to manage file uploads.

The problem is that when I insert an image into the CKEditor and adjust the width/height, it is not saved.

I am using Full HTML for the input format, so I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might be a known issue. See this thread for info: http://drupal.org/node/731068